# Remove random noise from image

Tags: java, image, pixel, bufferedimage

How can I "clean up" this image? I need to remove the black spots (noise).

I'm using java.

**Cleaned Captcha:**
[image: Cleaned Captcha]

**Original Captcha:**
[image]

```
public static BufferedImage paintComponent(BufferedImage image) {
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++) {
            int rgb = image.getRGB(j, i);

            if (cores.contains(rgb)) {

                image.setRGB(j, i, -1);
            }
        }
    }
    return image;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 105; i++) {
    int color = 150 + i;
    Color cor3 = new Color(color, color, color);
    int corint3 = cor3.getRGB();
    cores.add(corint3);
}
```

Comment: The wanted operation is called [Opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_(morphology)). Lots of image manipulation libraries should provide it.

Comment: Do you want to clean the first or the second image? What is `cores`? You are using a strange way to find gray pixels, it's simpler and faster to analyze the RGB values as they are. To determine if a black pixel is an isolated point, you must analyze its neighboring pixels.

Comment: Any of Them, but i need the image clean

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use median filter. This shall solve the problem of noise which is present in the form of dots in the image.

Comment: While this may be true, you should try to add to the asker’s example with a method which will help solve the problem.